# How soon after starting is StreetPass available?

Tags: bravely-default

How far into *Bravely Default* do I have to go to activate StreetPass in the game?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just after the first cave (which is the tutorial too), you'll get Agnes's Pendant, which allows you to use StreetPass. It will let you send or receive friends or guest attacks.

So, about 1 hour of game time if you start a new game, search everywhere, and read all dialogue.

If you skip everything, 30 minutes should be enough.

Comment: Ok, then. For initial StreetPassing then I should just use the demo, go home, play the demo one last time, import my game, and then start up a new game in the retail version. Man I hope they do a midnight release.

Comment: Midnight release?

Comment: @DrakaSAN: Bravely Default hasn't been released in the Americas yet. I'm guessing CyberSkull is in that region, and wants a midnight release with plenty of other people around (for more StreetPasses).

Comment: @MichaelMadsen: Wow, That must be the first time a game is launched in Europe before US XD

Comment: @DrakaSAN: Layton 6 was earlier still, and there have been several other titles like that (not to mention Europe gets physical releases of a few games that are eShop-only in US, e.g. Senran Kagura Burst). The inverse does still happen though (e.g. Etrian Odyssey IV came out much later in Europe than US), and we do still miss out completely on some titles (Rune Factory 4! ;_;), but the situation is generally much, much better than it was just a few years ago.

Comment: From what I'm told there weren't enough pre-orders for a midnight release in my area. 